# Is there a Java equivalent for cqlsh COPY FROM command?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I am trying to achieve something with BULK LOAD of data into Cassandra table in Java from a CSV file.

I am able to do that using cqlsh with the following COPY FROM command, I want to achieve the same programmatically, hopefully with decent performance as the COPY command

'''
COPY Keyspace1.table1 FROM 'C:\cassandradata\priceinfo.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' and HEADER = true;
'''

Looking for a Java way of handling this using any Open Source Cassandra Driver (JDBC/ODBC). I am fine to use Spring Data JPA as well.

Thanks for your guidance in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The [**DataStax Bulk Loader**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) tool (DSBulk) was written specifically for this purpose. It allows you to bulk load data in CSV or JSON format to Cassandra. You can also use DSBulk to export data from Cassandra to CSV or JSON.

It makes no sense to develop another Java app and reinvent the wheel. DSBulk is fully open-source so it's free to use.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

Comment: Thanks Erick for info on DSBulk utility, but my requirement is an SDK or API which I can invoke from my Java application to load data from csv file to cassandra table.